# Custom Layout in panels width

Tags: theming, 6, panels

I am working with a fluid 100% theme with [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) 6.x-3.9.

I have created a custom layout in Panels; it is based on threecol_25_50_25_stacked (First column is 25%, center is 50%, and last is 25%), and I created it for a 20/50/30 layout.

In the original threecol_25_50_25_stacked CSS file, the code is:

```css
.panel-3col-stacked .panel-col-first { 
  float: left; 
  width: 25%;
}

.panel-3col-stacked .panel-col .inside { 
  margin: 0 .5em 1em .5em;
}

.panel-3col-stacked .panel-col { 
  float: left; 
  width: 50%; 
}

.panel-3col-stacked .panel-col .inside { 
  margin: 0 .5em 1em .5em;
}

.panel-3col-stacked .panel-col-last { 
  float: left; 
  width: 25%; 
}

.panel-3col-stacked .panel-col-last .inside { 
  margin: 0 0 1em .5em;
}
```

In my CSS for the custom layout, I changed the widths to 20%, 50%, 30%, respectively.
When I resize the browser window, and dragging it smaller, the first column gets overlapped with the center column.  With all padding and margins unchanged, it should not do this, should it?
The original layout 25/50/25 does not do this.  What am I missing?

Here is a breakdown of what I have tested:

- Garland
  Original 25/50/25 Stacked: overlaps
  Custom 20/50/30 Stacked: overlaps
- Acquia Propser Fluid (Fusion sub-theme)
  Original 25/50/25 Stacked: does not overlap
  Custom 20/50/30 Stacked: overlaps
- Fusion Core Fluid
  Original 25/50/25 Stacked: does not overlap
  Custom 20/50/30 Stacked: overlaps
- Zen Core Fluid
  Original 25/50/25 Stacked: does not overlap
  Custom 20/50/30 Stacked: overlaps
- CTI Flex (Zen Sub-theme) Fluid
  Original 25/50/25 Stacked: does not overlap
  Custom 20/50/30 Stacked: overlaps

  [image: it doesn't overlap]

  [image: it does overlap]

Comment: Hello, picxelplay; welcome on _Drupal Answers_. Did you try changing the theme used by the website?

Comment: Hello, yes I have.  Tested on Fusion core, 3 Fusion sub themes, Zen Core, and 2 Zen sub themes.

Comment: @picxelplay I would also try with one of the core themes, including Garland. Sometimes it is just a problem of compatibility between a third-party module and a theme, or a group of themes.

Comment: Sorry I should have also mentioned, that it does not overlap with the themes mentioned in fixed width, but it does overlap in Garland (Garland is fluid)

Comment: @picxelplay There is nothing to be sorry. Thank you for the additional information, which would help who answers to give a more correct answer.

Comment: I need to edit my question to include the themes I have testing, but I can't because it says I need 10 reps to post images now.  What can I do?  It is too long to post in a comment.

Comment: @picxelplay I am commented out the images, so you should be able to edit your answer. Once you are done editing the answer, I will restore the images.

Comment: Ok done.  I actually put the images back to plain urls, and I was able to save my edits.  You can put them back to embedded screens now.  Thanks

Comment: @picxelplay I'm so sry if your tested this before. Are you sure that you not just missed a media query or have one over 100% col? (just ask because this display remindes me of my first grid ^^)